# MREF tool and TeX formatting

Tags: latex, bibliography

For sometime I have used the very useful [MathSciNet MRef tool](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/freetools/mref).  It allows one to input a citation (e.g. from zbMath or from MRLookup, if you don't have MathSciNet access, as I didn't for a while, and still don't conveniently when out of the office) and obtain canonically formatted citations in a variety of formats.

I'm not a big user of BiBTeX (maybe I should be) and so I appreciated MRef's ability to output canonically formatted TeX code which I could paste into a manual `thebibliography` environment in LaTeX.  However, since MRef was redesigned, it simply says "TeX format is temporarily unavailable."

> Does anyone have some insider knowledge as to when TeX formatting might return?

> Are there any other (free) tools which do a similar thing?

(I know I should have a better bibliography management system, but as I get older, I discover that time is my limiting factor in many things, and so it's nice to just have a simple system which adequately works, which MRef used to...)

Comment: You could try sending a message to the MR support staff: https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/help/support. I have occasionally gotten useful information that way.

Comment: You should learn to use BibTeX.

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/q/20551/4194

Comment: Just an update: I contacted MR support back in September, but got no response.  The TeX formatting option still doesn't work, but thankfully the access to the "old" version of MRef, given in the answer below, does still work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the moment, you can access the old version of mathscinet, including this, at https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/2006/mathscinet - I have to admit that I don't like the new version for several reasons.

Comment: MRef itself can be accessed at https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/2006/mref which works even if you don't have a subscription (as I don't off-campus).  Thanks!  This is a work-around for now.